# Find a formula for the sum of the first $n$ even positive numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of creating a formula to represent:
$0 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2n$ when $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

Looking it up I see that it is $n(n+1)$

However I can't figure out how to get there, I'm lost on the steps that go from $\sum_{i=0}^n 2i $ to  $ = n(n+1)$

I tried solving $a_nr^n+a_{n-1}r^{n-1}+a_{n-2}r^{n-2} = 0$ for $a_0 = 0$, $a_1=2$, $a_2=4$... but I don't think thats correct.

Comment: Do you know how to sum the first $n$ positive numbers?

Comment: One option would be proof by induction

Comment: If you already know how to sum the first $n$ integers, then you could use $$\sum_{i = 1}^n 2i = 2\sum_{i = 1}^n i.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

First $n$ even numbers look like
$$
2 + 4 + 6 + \ldots (2n-4) + (2n-2) + 2n.
$$
Sum them pairwise, grouping first with last, 2nd with next-to-last, etc, and you will find each sum is exactly $2n+2$.

How many pairs are there, and are there any non-paired elements?

Comment: ah - got it... $(2n+2)$ appears $n/2$ times!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2i =\sum_{j=0}^n 2(n-j)=2n(n+1)-\sum_{j=0}^n 2j$$

Comment: I was prepared to accuse your solution of circularity, but then I noticed it's actually very clever. +1

Comment: Very nice. +1..

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}2\times\bigl(2+4+\cdots(2n)\bigr)&=2+4+\cdots(2n)+(2n)+(2n-2)+\cdots+2\\&=\bigl(2+(2n)\bigr)+\bigl(4+(2n-2)\bigr)+\cdots+\bigl((2n)+2\bigr)\\&=n\times(2n+2).\end{align}